# (C#) Silverlight TextBox Scroll to Bottom

Tags: c#, silverlight, textbox, scroll

I want to get a `Textbox` to autoscroll to bottom whenever it gets updated with text, but it seems that there is no such method in Silverlight. In Windows Forms, I would do it this way:

```
textbox_txt.SelectionStart = textbox_txt.Text.Length;
textbox_txt.ScrollToCaret();
```

In Windows Presentation Foundation, I would do it this way:

```
textbox_txt.SelectionStart = textbox_txt.Text.Length;
textbox_txt.ScrollToEnd();
```

Now how the heck do I do this in Silverlight? there is no such scroll method anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActualHeight` contains the total height of the text. You can wrap text into the scroll view as described [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/117698/265050.aspx)

Comment: When I tried this, it infuriated me by scrolling to a spot a whole line above the bottom.